# Is using optional URL segments bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, internationalization, multilingual

I have a multilanguage site with urls like this

```
https://example.org/en/ads/2
https://example.org/es/ads/2
https://example.org/it/ads/2
```

which serve the site in different languages. My site also accepts URLs like this

```
https://example.org/ads/2
```

In that case the content is served in the default language (Spanish).

The site does not generate any URLs without locale. It accepts this kind of URLs, but then any following links for internal navigation are generated with the default locale (es).

I've been told that this is bad for SEO because different URLs (https://example.org/ads/2, https://example.org/es/ads/2) serve the same content.

Is this true? If yes, why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you canonicalise appropriately, it is fine. Use `rel="canonical"` to specify that the pages are identical, and hreflang for the alternate languages.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.org/es/ads/2">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.org/en/ads/2">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://example.org/es/ads/2">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="https://example.org/it/ads/2">
```